# Django CMS Group/Nest Placeholders

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cms

I'm trying to group my placeholders in Django CMS so that they don't appear in one long list. I want some sort of indication that some placeholders are linked together other than just their name.

Currently I want the user to be able to choose their own Header Image, Title and Subtitle so my placeholder tree looks like this:

-- Header Image

-- Header Title

-- Header Subtitle

I want to be able to group these together in my template to show a correlation like so:

-- Header

---- Header Image

---- Header Title

----  Header Subtitle

I found [a post from 2013](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/2471) that said this was possible but the plugin that was suggested that would give this functionality no longer exists.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to nest placeholders in djangoCMS 3.

Comment: @creimers that's a shame, seems like something that could easily be implemented and improve the UI a great deal when dealing with lots of placeholders

Comment: @samroberts707 you can group / nest plugins. In your case, you can create a custom Header plugin which allows only three plugins inside of it (image, title, subtitle).

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in django-cms 3.

What you do is you create you placeholder in your template as normal.  Then when you go to edit the page, find the empty placeholder that you just created and click the plus sign to add a plugin ie a text plugin called 'Header'. Then click the same plus sign to add a second text plugin. ie a text plugin called 'subheader' and so on.

You can mix different types of plugins and, like CMS pages on the menus, you can reorder your plugins by dragging them with the left drag tab.

Alternatively if you want things a little more tightly nested, you can add a text plugin to your placeholder.  The when you edit the text, the toolbar has a link to allow you to add other plugins ie links, images etc, within the parent text plugin.

I know this is a fairly old question but I just stumbled across it so maybe this might help someone else.